# Should I create a UITableViewCell class to every table in my app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uitableview

Hi I am new to iOS development, I am using swift 5 on Xcode 11.0 and I know how to create a table view and display data but I have some questions related to clean code and best practices:

1- Should I create a UITableViewCell class for every cell in the same table? Or one class for all the cells in the same table?

2- Can I use the same UITableViewCell class for different tables on different pages?

I watched several online tutorials but they all just explain how to create a table and don't go into that many details.

Comment: 1. If cells have the same design, you should have a single prototype for the cells.  2. Yes, you can.   Look ate tableView documentation in Xcode, at 'Configuring the Cells for Your Table'

Comment: You can have different cells in one table view, and you can have the same cell in multiple table views. But you don't have to, it depends on your design.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @claude31

Comment: Oh okay I guess depending on the design summarizes the answer, thank you @koen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question you can in fact utilize the same UITabelViewCell for different cells it is just a question of how much of the design they share and how much code will you have to repeat if you differentiate them.

Yes, Actually if your UITabelViewCell is use in different TableViews then you'll need to externalize your cell thus meaning you need to put it outside your TableView in a Xib or created programmatically and then register that cell like this in each TableView you'll use it.

```
//Created programmatically
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell-identifier")

//From a Xib
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "Nib-identifier", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell-identifier")
```

**Note:** Put the identifier in a static variable inside the class (also your nib if you have one) like this:

```
//  https://gist.github.com/JCTec/e64e34e204a6bb99ef92f73b2ee0ee7d
//  String+LoadNib.swift
//  Created by Juan Carlos Estevez on 17/12/19.
extension String {
    /// Carga un Archivo Nib con el nombre de la cadena de texto.
    ///
    /// - Parameter bundle: Bundle a agregar.
    /// - Returns: UINib.
    func loadNib(bundle: Bundle? = nil) -> UINib? {
        return UINib(nibName: self, bundle: bundle)
    }
}


class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier: String = "cell-identifier"
    static var nib: UINib! = {
        return "nib-identifier".loadNib()
    }()
}

//Use it like this
//Created programmatically
tableView.register(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: MyTableViewCell.identifier)

//From a Xib
tableView.register(MyTableViewCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: MyTableViewCell.identifier)
```

Comment: And btw welcome to iOS development . also CollectionView do the same as TableView but have more skills, considere using more CollectionViews than TableViews. @S.Hasan

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you for the explanation I get it better now.
And thanks for the CollectionView tip I will look it up (Y) @Juan Carlos